# Are cookies guarantied to be ready on time for redirected page?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have the following scenario :

- user goes to *www.mysite.com/someProduct*
- this is rewritten internally to */products.php?p=someProduct*
- in *product.php*, I detect that this user is currently logged in so I want to switch to his specific url but I still want to show the requested product, so I do:

  - set a "productRequest" cookie with "someProduct" in it
  - redirect with a location header to *www.mysite.com/theUser*
- the new location is internally rewritten to */users.php?u=theUser*
- in *users.php*, I may access the "productRequest" cookie (although not a use case right now)
- once the client gets served the user page, the javascript code will need to access the "requestProduct" cookie to perform some Ajax calls and fetch "someProduct" info.

Note that I do not want to pass "someProduct" in the user specific URL.

Also note that I could keep the request for "someProduct" in the user's SESSION on the server side but since that info is ultimately destined to javascript on the client's side, I find it somewhat ugly.

Now here is my question : are there any guaranties (would come from the http protocol I guess) that the cookie will always be received by the client before the redirect in order to be sent back to the newly requested page ?

THank you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  As soon as you set that cookie (which is done with an HTTP response header) the browser will begin using it in subsequent requests and it will be available to any JavaScript trying to access it.

Comment: Ok so if I read you correctly, the protocol ensures that the client agent will receive ALL headers before initiating the redirect ? So if this is correct, is it fair to say that even if the location header was sent before the cookie is set, the result would sill be good ?

Comment: @GillesjrBisson That's correct.  I have heard of old versions of IE requiring headers in specific order, but I think that was IE 4, and I don't think it related to cookies.